# SQL query with ROW_NUMBER not efficient in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have this query in SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.category ORDER BY (
        SELECT AVG(CAST(r.users AS NUMERIC)) FROM description r WHERE r.company = p.id
    ) DESC)  AS rownb, p.* FROM company p 
) rs WHERE rownb <= 2
```

The farthest I've come with converting this query to LINQ is:

```cs
Companies
    .SelectMany(r => 
        Descriptions
            .GroupBy(t => t.Company)
            .Select(t => new { 
                Average = t.Average(a => (double)a.Users), 
                Company = t.Key })
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.Average)
        , (p, r) => new { Companies = p, Descriptions = r })
    .Where(t => t.Companies.Id == t.Descriptions.Company)
    .GroupBy(t => t.Companies.Category)
    .Select(t => t.Take(2))
    .SelectMany(t => t)
    .Select(t => new { t.Companies.Name, t.Descriptions.Average, t.Companies.Category})
    .OrderBy(t => t.Category)
```

But the problem is the performance. While the SQL query cost is 28% (relative to the batch), the LINQ query is 72%.

I already replaced the Join with SelectMany in LINQ, which reduced by 20% the cost. But now I don't know how to optimize this query anymore.

Also, I understand there is no ROW_NUMBER in LINQ.

I'm using LINQPad to inspect the resulting SQL query.

**Question: Is ROW_NUMBER the responsible for this performance difference? Is it possible to optimize the LINQ query further?**

Comment: up voted you because i would really like to know the answer to this

Answer (score 0):

you can emulate row_number in your select like this

```
.Select((t,i) => new { rowindex = i+1, t.Companies.Name, t.Descriptions.Average, t.Companies.Category})
```

As for Optimizations, I'm not too sure.